# How to add columns with the same name into last line in order to have only one column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

There is a dataframe that contains several columns with the same name and I don't know the exact number of columns with the same. I want to keep only one column on my dataframe and add the the values of the other to the last line.

I don't know the best way to proceed.

Simple example below.

dataframe:

```
col_1 col_1 col_1 ... col_2 col_2 col_2
'abc' 'def' 'ghi' ... 123      456   789
```

expected output:

```
col_1 col_2
'abc'   123  
'def'   456
'ghi'   789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(df.melt()
   .assign(idx=lambda d: d.groupby('variable').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='idx', columns='variable', values='value')
   .reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Or:

```
(df.stack().to_frame()
   .pipe(lambda s: s.set_index(s.groupby(level=1).cumcount(), append=True))
   .unstack(level=1)[0].droplevel(0)
)
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2
0   abc   123
1   def   456
2   ghi   789
```

Comment: The second one worked well on my case. 
I don't know what excatly happened, but appreciate the help buddy.